# Photon speed in a medium with negative electric susceptibility

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, quantum-optics

In optical media, the real part of the electric susceptibility, Re{$\chi$}, can, in general, become negative for certain frequency ranges (near the absorption resonance). This leads to the refractive index, $n$, being less than one ($n \approx 1 + \frac{Re\{\chi\}}{2}<1$). It's noteworthy that when $n<1$, the phase speed of an electromagnetic (EM) wave within such media exceeds the speed of light in the vacuum. While some argue that the phase speed isn't a physical velocity, given its lack of relevance to information transfer, an intriguing question arises: What then becomes the **speed of a single photon in media with Re{$\chi$}$<0$**? Could it be said that, in general, the speed of a photon in a medium is $c_0/n$, with $c_0$ representing the speed of light in vacuum and $n$ denoting the refractive index of the medium? If not, what then is the speed of a photon in various media? Furthermore, how is the speed of a photon correlated with the phase speed of an electromagnetic wave?

Comment: Under what circumstances would this happen? Can you perhaps provide some references?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity